# Calling Image constructor on map returns an array of empty object

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I tried to create an array of HtmlImageElement using a map on an other array.

```
const foo = Array(5).map(() => new Image())
```

And I got an array full of empty object

[image: node example of the previous code line, returning "[<5 empty items>]"]

Why is that ?

Thanks !

Edit :

It looks like it is the case with any object constructed in a map

[image: node example of the same line of code but with a custom object, also returning an array of empty object]

Comment: Your list is of length 5 but contains "nothing", so you should fill it with something before you map. `Array(5).fill(undefined).map(() => new Image())`

Comment: After creating your array via `Array()` constructor, you have to call `.fill()` to set some value for every element in the array, then it can be `.map()`ed. Example: `Array(5).fill().map(() => ({any: 'object'}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array(5)` creates a new empty array of a length 5 with all the items as `undefined`. Calling `map()` on this empty array has no effect on the callback function (will not be executed).

To solve the issue, you can try `Array.from()` like following way:

```js
const foo = Array.from({length:5}, () => new Image());
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array

> arrayLength If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 232 - 1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number (**Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values — see sparse arrays**).

More explanation on sparse arrays here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#sparse_arrays